# How to format requirements.txt when package source is from specific websites?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, requirements.txt

I am trying to convert the following installation commands using pip that downloads from another website, into a requirements.txt format, but just can't figure out how. Can anyone assist?

```
pip install torch==1.5.0+cu101 torchvision==0.6.0+cu101 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html

pip install detectron2 -f https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/detectron2/wheels/cu101/index.html
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The [structure of the contents of a requirements.txt file](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/#structure) is defined as follows:

> ```
> [[--option]...]
> <requirement specifier> [; markers] [[--option]...]
> <archive url/path>
> [-e] <local project path>
> [-e] <vcs project url>
> ```

The [`<requirement specifier>`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#requirement-specifiers) defines the package and an optional version.

> ```
> SomeProject
> SomeProject == 1.3
> SomeProject >=1.2,<2.0
> SomeProject[foo, bar]
> SomeProject~=1.4.2
> ```

The `--option` (such as the [`-f`/`--find-links`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-f)) is the same as the [pip install options](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#options) you would use if you were doing `pip install` from the command line.

> The following options are supported:
>
> - -i, --index-url
> - --extra-index-url
> - --no-index
> - -c, --constraint
> - -r, --requirement
> - -e, --editable
> - -f, --find-links
> - --no-binary
> - --only-binary
> - --require-hashes
> - --pre
> - --trusted-host

So, for your install commands, the requirements.txt would look like this:

```
# Torch
--find-links https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
torch==1.5.0+cu101
torchvision==0.6.0+cu101

# Detectron
--find-links https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/detectron2/wheels/cu101/index.html
detectron2
```

Make sure to verify that the links are correctly used:

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt 
Looking in links: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html, https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/detectron2/wheels/cu101/index.html
Collecting torch==1.5.0+cu101 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Using cached https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu101/torch-1.5.0%2Bcu101-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl
Collecting torchvision==0.6.0+cu101 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
  Using cached https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu101/torchvision-0.6.0%2Bcu101-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl
Collecting detectron2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 8))
  Using cached https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/detectron2/wheels/cu101/detectron2-0.1.2%2Bcu101-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl
...
```

---

As a side note, you [originally said "(not github)"](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/61741997/1) in your title. The default source of packages installed using `pip` is hosted on PyPi: https://files.pythonhosted.org/. You can see the actual links when going to the **Download Files** section of a package in PyPi (example for [Torch](https://pypi.org/project/torch/#files)).

Comment: Note that --find-links xxxx and the package name need to be on separate lines for this to work.

Answer (score -6):

Mainly requirements.txt is a list of dependencies:

```
requests
bcrypt
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is about how to specify packages that need to be downloaded from websites, other than PyPI presumably.